# Casting, Generics, and Subtypes

Tags: c#, generics

In trying to implement the repository pattern I've run into a minor problem that I'm concerned actually belies bigger issues.

I've got a DatabaseEntity`<T>` which I'm using to handle all the basic CRUD operations and from which all other classes that need to be stored in a database will descend from.  It is working fine for classes that inherit directly from it, however when using it with classes that have an intermediate parent I've run into a problem.

Suppose I have three other classes, Parent, ChildA and ChildB and and the inheritance looks like:

DatabaseEntity
                 |
                                 Parent
                     |          |
                                     ChildA   ChildB

Also suppose that DatabaseEntity`<T>` has a method with the following signature:

```
public static T FindBy(int id)
```

The issue I'm having is when I try something like:

```
ChildA Foo = ChildA.FindBy(SomeID);
```

I get a compiler error telling me that there's no implicit conversion from a Parent to a ChildA.  This is because Parent is the class that's being passed in for the type parameter to DatabaseEntity for both ChildA and ChildB.  Easy fix I think, just add a type parameter to Parent thus passing through the appropriate type.  Only wait a second, then I'll have to explicitly define the subtype any time I'm using Parent which ruins any polymorphism.  No, on second thought maybe that's not such a great fix.

I think that I could just drop the type parameter on the class DatabaseEntity itself and have each method require a type parameter but then I'd have to do something like:

```
ChildA Foo = ChildA.FindBy<ChildA>(SomeID);
```

While that compiles, it seems less clean and certainly requires more typing.  Visual Studio asks if I'm missing a cast and while its true I could just cast my first example its only a matter of time before I accidentally type out:

```
ChildB Foo = (ChildB) ChildA.FindBy(SomeID)
```

I'm not especially pleased with any of the solutions I've thought of so far and I'm hoping someone here can point out an elegant one that I've missed.

Comment: Which .Net version are you constrained to?

Comment: you need an ORM which supports LINQ operations, then you can make use of `OfType<T>` to do the conversion between parent to childa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that making `Parent` a generic class is the way to go. You didn't explain what exactly is the purpose of the type `T` in your example, but I suppose you want it to be the actual type of the entity, so for example your `Parent` would inherit `Entity<Parent>`.

You can still write polymorphic code in this scenario - you just have to use generics:

```
static void Foo<T>(Parent<T> p) where T : Parent<T>
{
  Parent<T> entity = p.Find();
}
```

This method can be called with both `ChildA` and `ChildB`. The only tricky aspect is that you cannot actually create an instance of `Parent<Parent<...>>` (because the dots would have to be replaced with more nested `Parent<...>` types), but you can write somthing like this:

```
class ParentFix : Parent<ParentFix> { }
```

.. then you can pass instances of `ParentFix` to the `Foo` method as well.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could write a method definition like that, still getting used to Generics.  You are correct in assuming that I would like T to be the actual type of the entity.  As luck would have it, I don't need to instantiate Parent in this case.  Having an empty fixer class seems kind of ugly though (no offense), is this a common technique or have I inadvertently created a weird scenario?

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but I would recommend using a solid off-the-shelf ORM, like Entity Framework 4.  It supports inheritance out of the box, and it's basic, fundamental usage *is* a repository.

I think you're in for a lot of pain if you try to roll this yourself.

Comment: I'm actually using NHibernate, I'm trying to set up my DatabaseEntity class so I don't have to repeatedly add very basic Find/Delete/Save methods that call NHibernate for each of my classes.  NHibernate is already doing all the heavy lifting :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Im sorry if I dont get the bigger picture here, but you can make `DatabaseEntity<T>` a seperate Generic class (a static one may be), without deriving the `Parent` from it.</strike>

This arrangement would allow using all the CRUD operations defined with `DatabaseEntity<T>` with any of the classes you might have.

P.S.: Please dont flame me if I've missed out something obvious, I'd rather appriciate some clarification so that I can learn better.